# Last child of <ul> does not obey style of other children

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I have a ul with a sub ul as my dropdown navigation menu.
The sub ul lis are shown when clicking the dropdown buttons.

For some reason I cannot figure out, the last li of the sub ul does not obey to the styles set for all sub ul lis. In this case that is the max-height and also the animation.

Demonstration: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aKNwNj

> Edit: overflow:hidden on .dropdown > .topnav-item fixes it - thanks lipp

#### html

```
<nav id="topnav">
<ul class="topnav-box">
  <li class="topnav-item"><a class="link" href="">Home</a></li>
  <li class="topnav-item"><button class="button">Dropdown 1</button>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li class="topnav-item"><a class="link" href="">Test</a></li>
      <li class="topnav-item"><a class="link" href="">Not animating, Y?</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="topnav-item"><button class="button">DD 2</button>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li class="topnav-item"><a class="link" href="">Test</a></li>
      <li class="topnav-item"><a class="link" href="">Not animating, Y?</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="topnav-item"><button class="button">Big Dropdown</button>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li class="topnav-item"><a class="link" href="">Test</a></li>
      <li class="topnav-item"><a class="link" href="">Test</a></li>
      <li class="topnav-item"><a class="link" href="">Test</a></li>
      <li class="topnav-item"><a class="link" href="">Not animating, Y?</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="topnav-item"><a class="link" href="">About</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

#### sass

```
.topnav-box
  display: flex
  align-items: center

.topnav-item
  position: relative

  > .link
    white-space: nowrap
    display: block
    text-decoration: none
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px
    color: white
    background-color: orange
    font-size: 22px
    line-height: 100%
    &:hover
      background-color: white
      color: orange

  > .button
    border: none
    cursor: pointer
    margin: 0
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px
    color: white
    background-color: orange
    font-size: 22px
    line-height: 100%
    &:hover
      color: orange
      background-color: white

  //Show dropdown items when button has -js-active class
  > .button.-js-active
    + .dropdown
      > .topnav-item
          display: block

  > .dropdown
    position: absolute
    top: 100%
    min-width: 100%

    //Apparently this does not affect the last-child of .dropdown ul
    > .topnav-item
      display: none
      max-height: 0px
      @for $i from 1 through 12
        &:nth-of-type(#{$i})
          animation:
            name: subnav
            duration: 3000ms
            delay: (200ms * $i) - 200ms
            fill-mode: forwards

@keyframes subnav
  0%
    max-height: 0px
  100%
    max-height: 35px
```

#### jquery

```
function tglNavDropDown (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.topnav-item > button').not(this).removeClass('-js-active');
  $(this).toggleClass('-js-active');
}
$('.topnav-item > .button').click(tglNavDropDown);
```

Comment: it's flex fault

Comment: Just went and commented out the flex part and replaced it with a float:left only for the top level list items but that doesn't fix the problem of the last child in the dropdown ul.

Comment: did you update the pen?

Comment: Yep https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zaqdyv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style gets applied correctly to the last item. The problem is another. Even though you set `max-height=0px`, this does not prevent overflowing content from being visible. The last item is just the last rendered element and thus gets visible.

To fix this, you can apply `overflow: hidden` to either the `.topnav-item` ([demo](https://codepen.io/lipp/pen/gKrGXq)) or to the `.dropdown` ([demo](https://codepen.io/lipp/pen/xzVXWP))

Comment: Wow thank you so much, this fixes it. It seems very odd to me though that its only the last item that does this.

Comment: It is the last rendered item with relative position, so the last just gets on top.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `max-height` on the `ul.dropdown`, not the `<li>`.

Also you need to add `overflow: hidden` to the `ul.dropdown`

pen => https://codepen.io/tonysamperi/pen/qKZPxx

Comment: Thanks the overflow: hidden property fixed it. Although it only needs to be added to the <li> as lipp said. Also i do intend to set max-height to each <li> to animate them individually.

Comment: Ok, it seems a waste of computation, but...as you wish!